# Auto scroll on Keyboard appearance in UITableViewController broken only on iPad iOS8?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, ios8, keyboard, uitextfield

While testing a pre-release App I noticed that on my iOS8 iPad the appearance of the keyboard in a UITableViewController no longer invokes the auto-scroll/auto-resize.

I have a storyboard static table view in which the top 5 sections each have a single cell containing a UITextField.

The keyboard covers the last of these making it difficult for the user to input text as the table doesn't adjust it's scroll area to accommodate the keyboard height.

Testing on iOS7 iPad it works fine.
Testing on iOS7 & iOS8 on iPhone it also works fine.
Same code used on both iPhone & iPad.

I've search extensively and I've ruled out the usual suspects.
e.g.
 - not invoking [super viewWillAppear:animated]; (All viewWill super's are called)
 - having delegates set when not required.

So the only conclusion I can come to is that this is (yet another) bug in iOS8?

Anyone else seen this, got a solution or can think of something that I've not already checked?
I've seen a number of bugs in iOS8 with statically declared storyboard UI features, so this is probably just another.... Loathed to have to switch to programatically created.

EDIT:
I've deleted the view from both iPad & iPhone storyboards and completely rebuilt a new one.
Still same behaviour so it's not some quirk of storyboard encoding that's gotten broken migrating from Xcode 4 to 5 to 6.